# Get the loading progress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm thinking about making a gravatar link getter and I would like to add a loading screen but I don't know how to get loading progress with JavaScript when loading HTML and CSS assets

```js
let loadingpercent = percent();

function LoadProj()
{
  document.write("Hold On, your request is loading.<br> " + loadingpercent);
}

function percent()
{
    //Code Goes here
    return NaN;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="LoadProj()" value="LoadMe">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the percent in a variable and the interval at which the progress should increment in another (in ms).

Then, in your `LoadProj` function, increment the percent and set the `innerHTML` of the body to the right value. Check if the percent is not 100. If it is not, we can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to call `LoadProj` again with a delay, in our case, `loadInterval`. If it *is*, you know that it is finished loading, and you can handle it accordingly.

```js
var percent = 0;
var loadInterval = 100;

function LoadProj() {
  percent++;
  document.body.innerHTML = "Hold On, your request is loading. " + percent;
  if (percent != 100) {
    setTimeout(LoadProj, loadInterval)
  }else{
    //Finished loading! Your code here...
    console.log('Finished loading!')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="LoadProj()" value="LoadMe">
```

Comment: Would I be able to replace `var` with `let`

Comment: @CrimsonX yes, you would.